# c# Having trouble with adding

Tags: c#, addition

I am new to this so please be patient, I am having a bit of trouble with adding at the moment. I am trying to make it so every time you click the button it adds 5 to the total. Can anyone help me?

This is the class CashBox:

```
public string cash1()
{
   return "5";
}
```

This is the code when clicking on button:

```
CashBox fivepence;
fivepence = new CashBox();
txtMoney.Text = txtMoney.Text + fivepence.cash1();
total1 = total1 + double.Parse(txtMoney.Text);
```

If the button is pressed three times the outcome is 555 not 15.
Any help would be much appreciated!!

Comment: Whenever you're asking a question on SO, be sure to write what your problem is.

Comment: Really? We have an 'addition' tag? There are people interested specifically in questions involving the adding of numbers?

Comment: `"5"+"5" = "55"` you should use decimal not string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do things in the reverse order: first make the addition and then update the UI with the result. First of all, change `cash1` to `return 5` (an integer, not a string). Then:

```
// do the math
var subtotal = double.Parse(txtMoney.Text) + fivepence.cash1();

// update the user interface
txtMoney.Text = subtotal.ToString();

// update total1, whatever that is
total1 += subtotal;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to return integer `5`, not string. Your current method would return string and the result would be string concatenation not integer addition. Try:

```
  public int cash1()
  {
      return 5;
  }
```

And then:

```
txtMoney.Text = (double.Parse(txtMoney.Text) + fivepence.cash1()).ToString();
total1 = total1 + double.Parse(txtMoney.Text); //or total1 += double.Parse(txtMoney.Text);
```

Comment: shouldn't he cast the value to string before assigning it to `Text` property then ?

Comment: @Bartdude, not really sure , but I added it

Comment: You cannot cast the expression to a `string` as it is a `double`. Instead use `.ToString()`. That is `(double.Parse(txtMoney.Text) + fivepence.cash1()).ToString()`.